# How to get Default language of a video Youtube (api v3)

Tags: video, youtube-api

I need the default language of youtube videos. Based on this [doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#properties), it is possible to get the default language (snippet.defaultLanguage), but when I run a simple test in there API explorer, I can't get this value, Is it available only for some videos or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an optional field set by the video author. If the author does not set the default language, it will not appear in the snippet.

Comment: mm.. I see, I noticed that the majority doesn't have a default language, so I guess I have to write my own script to detect languages. Another question @johnh10, could it be possible to get a set of videos (search by keywords-Search.List-) along withe the there related videos with one single query, instead of requesting related videos for each videoID?

Comment: No the Search.list `relatedToVideoId` parameter only accepts one videoID so it would take multiple queries.